# Powershell prints variables out of order

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm brand new to powershell, and I'm finding a very odd behavior when I try and pass a parameter into a function:

Code

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$vhdSourceDir,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$vhdDestinationDir,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][array]$hypervisorList,
  [int]$vhdKeep = 10
)


function getDirectoryBuildNumber ($dir) {

    # Returns a number like 627c6ddeb8776914 from a path like: 
    # c:\BulidAgent\work\627c6ddeb8776914\packer\windows\box\hyperv\win2012r2std-cheflatest-001.box
    return ( Get-ChildItem $dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[A-Za-z0-9]{16}$" } | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 )
}


function findBoxFile ($dir, $build) {

    echo "looking for build $build at $dir "
    echo "the dir is $dir and the build is $build"
    # e.g c:\BulidAgent\work\627c6ddeb8776914\packer\windows\box\hyperv\win2012r2std-cheflatest-001.box
    return ( Get-ChildItem $dir\$build\packer\windows\box\hyperv\ | Where-Object Extension -in '.box' | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 )
}

Function Main ()
{
    $THEBUILD=getDirectoryBuildNumber($vhdSourceDir)
    echo "THEBUILD is $THEBUILD"
    findBoxFile($vhdSourceDir,$THEBUILD)
    #echo "BOXFILE is $BOXFILE"

}
main
```

Problem

Here are the parameters that I call the script with:

```
.\boxMove.ps1 -vhdSourceDir C:\BuildAgent\work -vhdDestinationDir e:\ -hypervisorList 'foobar'
```

Here is the output it generates

```
THEBUILD is 527c6ddeb8776914
looking for build  at C:\BuildAgent\work 527c6ddeb8776914 
the dir is C:\BuildAgent\work 527c6ddeb8776914 and the build is 
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\BuildAgent\work 527c6ddeb8776914\packer\windows\box\hyperv\' because it does not exist.
```

The parameters show up out of order. For example, the phrase 'looking for build should appear like so"

```
looking for build 527c6ddeb8776914  at C:\BuildAgent\work
```

but it shows up as

```
looking for build  at C:\BuildAgent\work 527c6ddeb8776914
```

Also the phrase 'the dir is..' should read

```
the dir is C:\BuildAgent\work and the build is 527c6ddeb8776914
```

but it reads as

```
the dir is C:\BuildAgent\work 527c6ddeb8776914 and the build is
```

Why is powershell not printing the strings in order?

Comment: First: Do not use parentheses to call PowerShell functions.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass parameters to functions do not encapsulate them in parentheses and where multiple parameters are being passed, they should **not** be comma separated, instead a space should be used to separate them.

For instance:

```
findBoxFile($vhdSourceDir,$THEBUILD)
```

should read:

```
findBoxFile $vhdSourceDir $THEBUILD
```

Then you'll find that this removes the issue you were encountering with the incorrectly ordered output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, clean up your function definitions. Instead of

```
function (params){code}
```

you should use

```
function
{
Param ($Param1,$param2)
code
}
```

Also, when accepting an array as a param, instead of using [array], specify the array type, (probably string in your case), so that would be (line 4)

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$hypervisorList,
```

It's hard do say exactly why the script fails, but I'd start by cleaning up the obvious issues and test again.